# How to retrieve data from sqlite database and display in a fragment

Tags: sqlite, android-fragments, android-sqlite, android-fragmentactivity

I want to display data from my DB into a EditText in my fragment.

Here is my coding:

**DBhelper**

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("Create table Tenant_login(name text, email text primary key, password text)" );
}
```

**Retrive Data**

```
 public Cursor alldata() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery("Select * from Tenant_login",null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

**Fragment class**

```
public class profileFragement extends Fragment {

    DatabaseHelper db;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment, container, false);
        EditText et = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        et.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);


     db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    Cursor cursor = db.alldata();
      et.setText(""+ cursor.getString(0));
 return view;
    }

}
```

This coding is giving me no results.
Please Help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must move the cursor's index to the 1st row (if it exists):

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    et.setText("" + cursor.getString(0));
}
```